# Flutter Bloc doesn't update data in UI using BLOC pattern

Tags: flutter, user-interface, state, updates, bloc

I am working on an ordering application. where I have an object called "Comanda" that contains a list of objects called "CommandLine". I want to handle with the BLOC pattern the whole issue of adding lines to the command, deleting and/or editing.

I show the implemented code.

CLASSES:

```
class Comanda extends Equatable {
  Comanda({this.lineasComanda = const <LineaComanda>[], this.mesa, this.zona});

  List<LineaComanda> lineasComanda;
  Mesa? mesa;
  Zona? zona;

  factory Comanda.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Comanda(
      lineasComanda: json["lineasComanda"] ?? [],
      mesa: Mesa.fromJson(json["mesa"]),
      zona: Zona.fromJson(json["mesa"]));

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "lineasComanda": lineasComanda,
        "mesa": mesa != null ? mesa!.toJson() : null,
        "zona": zona != null ? zona!.toJson() : null,
      };

  Comanda copyWith({
    List<LineaComanda>? lineasComanda,
    Mesa? mesa,
    Zona? zona,
  }) {
    return Comanda(
      lineasComanda: lineasComanda!,
      mesa: mesa ?? this.mesa,
      zona: zona ?? this.zona,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [lineasComanda, mesa, zona];
}

class LineaComanda extends Equatable {
  LineaComanda({
    required this.articulo,
    required this.unidades,
    this.unidadesPendientes = 0,
    this.anotaciones,
  });

  Articulo? articulo;
  int unidades;
  int unidadesPendientes;
  List<String>? anotaciones = [];

  //UI VARIALBLES
  bool isExpanded = false;

  LineaComanda copyWith(
      {Articulo? articulo,
      int unidades = 0,
      int unidadesPendientes = 0,
      List<String>? anotaciones = const []}) {
    return LineaComanda(
      articulo: articulo ?? this.articulo,
      unidades: unidades,
      unidadesPendientes: unidadesPendientes,
      anotaciones: anotaciones ?? this.anotaciones,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [articulo, unidades, unidadesPendientes, anotaciones];
}
```

BLOC:

```
part of 'Comanda_bloc.dart';


abstract class ComandaState extends Equatable {
  const ComandaState();
}

class ComandaInitial extends ComandaState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class ComandaLoading extends ComandaState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class ComandaLoaded extends ComandaState {
  final Comanda comanda;

  const ComandaLoaded({required this.comanda});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [comanda];
}

class ComandaError extends ComandaState {
  final String error;

  const ComandaError(this.error);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [error];
}





part of 'Comanda_bloc.dart';

abstract class ComandaEvent extends Equatable {
  const ComandaEvent();
}

class StartComanda extends ComandaEvent {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class AddLineaComanda extends ComandaEvent {
  final LineaComanda lineaComanda;

  const AddLineaComanda(this.lineaComanda);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [lineaComanda];
}

class RemoveLineaComanda extends ComandaEvent {
  final LineaComanda lineaComanda;

  RemoveLineaComanda(this.lineaComanda);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [lineaComanda];
}

class AddUnidades extends ComandaEvent {
  final LineaComanda lineaComanda;

  AddUnidades(this.lineaComanda);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [lineaComanda];
}

class RemoveUnidades extends ComandaEvent {
  final LineaComanda lineaComanda;

  RemoveUnidades(this.lineaComanda);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [lineaComanda];
}

class RemoveAllLineaComanda extends ComandaEvent {
  final LineaComanda lineaComanda;

  RemoveAllLineaComanda(this.lineaComanda);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [lineaComanda];
}

class SelectMesa extends ComandaEvent {
  final Mesa mesa;

  SelectMesa(this.mesa);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [mesa];
}

class LoadComanda extends ComandaEvent {
  final List<LineaComanda> lineasComanda;

  LoadComanda(this.lineasComanda);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [lineasComanda];
}



part 'Comanda_event.dart';
part 'Comanda_state.dart';

class ComandaBloc extends Bloc<ComandaEvent, ComandaState> {
  final Comanda_Repository repository;

  ComandaBloc(this.repository) : super(ComandaInitial()) {
    //EVENTOS

    on<LoadComanda>((event, emit) async {
      emit(ComandaLoading());
      try {
        // final comanda = await repository.getone(1);

        emit(ComandaLoaded(comanda: Comanda()));
      } catch (error) {
        emit(ComandaError(error.toString()));
      }
    });

    on<StartComanda>((event, emit) async {
      emit(ComandaLoading());
      try {
        // final comanda = await repository.getone(1);

        emit(ComandaLoaded(comanda: Comanda()));
      } catch (error) {
        emit(ComandaError(error.toString()));
      }
    });

    on<AddLineaComanda>((event, emit) async {
      final state = this.state;
      if (state is ComandaLoaded) {
        try {
          emit(
            ComandaLoaded(
                comanda: state.comanda.copyWith(
                    lineasComanda: List.from(state.comanda.lineasComanda)
                      ..add(event.lineaComanda))),
          );
        } catch (_) {}
      }
    });

    on<RemoveLineaComanda>((event, emit) async {
      final state = this.state;
      if (state is ComandaLoaded) {
        try {
          emit(
            ComandaLoaded(
                comanda: state.comanda.copyWith(
                    lineasComanda: List.from(state.comanda.lineasComanda)
                      ..remove(event.lineaComanda))),
          );
        } catch (_) {}
      }
    });

    on<AddUnidades>((event, emit) async {
      emit(ComandaLoading());
      final state = this.state;
      if (state is ComandaLoaded) {
        try {
          if (state.comanda.lineasComanda.contains(event.lineaComanda)) {
 
            List<LineaComanda> lineasComanda = state.comanda.lineasComanda;

            lineasComanda.firstWhere((item) => item == event.lineaComanda).unidades += 1;

            emit(
              ComandaLoaded(comanda: state.comanda.copyWith(lineasComanda: lineasComanda)),
            );
          
          }
        } catch (_) {}
      }
    });

    on<RemoveUnidades>((event, emit) async {
      final state = this.state;
      if (state is ComandaLoaded) {
        try {
          if (state.comanda.lineasComanda.contains(event.lineaComanda)) {
            List<LineaComanda> lineasComanda = state.comanda.lineasComanda;

            lineasComanda.firstWhere((item) => item == event.lineaComanda).unidades -= 1;

            emit(
              ComandaLoaded(comanda: state.comanda.copyWith(lineasComanda: lineasComanda)),
            );
          }

          // LineaComanda lineaComanda =
          //     state.comanda.lineasComanda.firstWhere((element) => element == event.lineaComanda);

        } catch (_) {}
      }
    });
  }
}
```

UI:

```
class Comanda extends StatefulWidget {
  const Comanda({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Comanda> createState() => _ComandaState();
}

class _ComandaState extends State<Comanda> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: BlocBuilder<ComandaBloc, ComandaState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is ComandaLoading) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            if (state is ComandaLoaded) {
              return state.comanda.lineasComanda.isEmpty
                  ? const EmptyList(
                      text: 'No existen artículos en la comanda',
                    )
                  : ListView(children: [
                      ExpansionPanelList(
                        elevation: 3,
                        // dividerColor: Colors.blue,
                        expandedHeaderPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        expansionCallback: (index, isExpanded) {
                          setState(() {
                            state.comanda.lineasComanda[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
                          });
                        },
                        animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                        children: state.comanda.lineasComanda
                            .map(
                              (item) => LineaComandaCard(item),
                            )
                            .toList(),
                        // Card_lineaComanda(flatButtonStyle),
                      ),
                    ]);
            }

            if (state is ComandaError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(state.error.toString()),
              );
            }
            return Container();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  ExpansionPanel LineaComandaCard(LineaComanda lineaComanda) {
    //Conusltamos el color de la famila

    Color color = Colors.grey;
    ;

    // do stuff here based on BlocA's state

    return ExpansionPanel(
      canTapOnHeader: true,
      // backgroundColor: item['isExpanded'] == true ? Colors.cyan[100] : Colors.white,
      headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) {
        return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
                border: Border(left: BorderSide(color: color, width: 3))),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(lineaComanda.articulo!.nombre, style: AppTheme.tituloCard),
                Row(
                  // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    AnimatedSwitcher(
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Unidades:',
                            style: AppTheme.textTagsCard,
                          ),
                          BlocBuilder<ComandaBloc, ComandaState>(
                            builder: (context, state) {
                              if (state is ComandaLoaded)
                                return Text(
                                  ' ${state.comanda.lineasComanda.firstWhere((item) => item == lineaComanda).unidades}',
                                  style: AppTheme.textTagsCard,
                                  key: ValueKey(lineaComanda.unidades),
                                );

                              return Container();
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
                        return ScaleTransition(scale: animation, child: child);
                      },
                    ),

                    const Text("  |  "),

                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 2),
                      child: Text(
                        'Pendientes: ${lineaComanda.unidades}',
                        style: AppTheme.textTagsCard,
                      ),
                    ),

                    (lineaComanda.unidadesPendientes >= lineaComanda.unidades)
                        ? const Icon(
                            Icons.check_box_rounded,
                            color: AppTheme.greenOscuro,
                            size: 15,
                          )
                        : (lineaComanda.unidades == lineaComanda.unidadesPendientes)
                            ? const Icon(Icons.disabled_by_default_rounded,
                                color: AppTheme.redOscuro, size: 15)
                            : const Icon(Icons.indeterminate_check_box_rounded,
                                color: AppTheme.yellow, size: 15),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),

                    // const SizedBox(
                    //   width: 20,
                    // ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ));
      },
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 3, left: 10, right: 10),
            child: Text(
              "Anotaciones:",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            ),
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 30),
            child: Text(
              "· Sin pepinillo.",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            ),
          ),
          const Divider(),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              // alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              // buttonHeight: 12.0,
              // buttonMinWidth: 10.0,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  // style: flatButtonStyle,
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<ComandaBloc>()..add(AddUnidades(lineaComanda));

                  
                    // setState(() {
                    //   lineaComanda.unidades += 1;
                    // });
                  },
                  child: Column(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        color: AppTheme.grismedio,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Más',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9, color: AppTheme.secondaryTextColor),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  // style: flatButtonStyle,
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<ComandaBloc>()..add(RemoveUnidades(lineaComanda));
                   
                    // setState(() {

                    //   // lineaComanda.unidades -= 1;
                    // });
                  },
                  child: Column(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.remove,
                        color: AppTheme.grismedio,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Menos',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9, color: AppTheme.secondaryTextColor),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  // style: flatButtonStyle,
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Column(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.edit_note_outlined,
                        color: AppTheme.grismedio,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Anotaciones',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9, color: AppTheme.secondaryTextColor),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  // style: flatButtonStyle,
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<ComandaBloc>()..add(RemoveLineaComanda(lineaComanda));
                  },
                  child: Column(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.delete_outline_outlined,
                        color: AppTheme.grismedio,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Eliminar',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9, color: AppTheme.secondaryTextColor),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  // style: flatButtonStyle,
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Column(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.local_offer_outlined,
                        color: AppTheme.grismedio,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Invitar',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9, color: AppTheme.secondaryTextColor),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      isExpanded: lineaComanda.isExpanded,
    );
  }
}
```

The add and remove command line events do work correctly and the UI is redrawed, but the add and remove unit events do not redraw the UI, although the event is executed.

I show console logs:

ADD/REMOVE Command Line:

I/flutter (13260): ComandaBloc AddLineaComanda(LineaComanda(Article(389, , CHIVITO BOCADILLO, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10, YesNO.No, YesNO.No, YesNO.No, -1, 0, - 1, YesNO.No, YesNO.No), 2, 0, [])) I/flutter (13260): Transition { currentState: CommandLoaded(Command([], null, null)), event: AddCommandLine(CommandLine(Item (389, , CHIVITO SNACK, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10, YesNO.No, YesNO.No, YesNO.No, -1, 0, -1, YesNO.No, YesNO.No), 2, 0, [])), nextState: CommandLoaded(Command([CommandLine(Article(389, , CHIVITO BOCADILLO, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10, SioNO.No, SioNO.No, SioNO.No, -1 , 0, -1, YesNO.No, YesNO.No), 2, 0, [])], null, null)) }

ADD / REMOVE UNITS:

I/flutter (13260): CommandBloc AddUnits(CommandLine(Article(389, , CHIVITO BOCADILLO, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10, YesNO.No, YesNO.No, YesNO.No, -1, 0, - 1, YesNO.No, YesNO.No), 4, 0, []))

Any solution to redraw the UI correctly???

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you handle `RemoveLineaComanda` and `AddLineaComanda` events, you create a new instance of a `List` with `List.from()`.
In the case of the `RemoveUnidades` and `AddUnidades` you emit a state with the same instance of `List` from the previous state. If you create a new List in for these events as well it should work properly.

This implementation works for me:

```
    on<AddUnidades>((event, emit) async {
      final state = this.state;
      if (state is ComandaLoaded) {
        try {
          if (state.comanda.lineasComanda.contains(event.lineaComanda)) {
            List<LineaComanda> lineasComanda = state.comanda.lineasComanda;

            // find the order of the event
            int index = lineasComanda.indexOf(event.lineaComanda);

            // make a new list from the state.
            List<LineaComanda> nuevaLista = List.of(lineasComanda);

            // edit the order by creating a new LineaComanda to replace the edited one.
            nuevaLista[index] = lineasComanda[index]
                .copyWith(unidades: lineasComanda[index].unidades + 1);

            // emit a new state with the new list of orders.
            emit(
              ComandaLoaded(
                  comanda: state.comanda.copyWith(lineasComanda: nuevaLista)),
            );
          }
        } catch (_) {}
      }
    });
```

Similarly `RemoveUnidades` should become:

```
on<RemoveUnidades>((event, emit) async {
      final state = this.state;
      if (state is ComandaLoaded) {
        try {
          if (state.comanda.lineasComanda.contains(event.lineaComanda)) {
            List<LineaComanda> lineasComanda = state.comanda.lineasComanda;

            int index = lineasComanda.indexOf(event.lineaComanda);

            // make a new list from the state.
            List<LineaComanda> nuevaLista = List.of(lineasComanda);

            // edit the order by creating a new LineaComanda to replace the edited one.
            nuevaLista[index] = lineasComanda[index]
                .copyWith(unidades: lineasComanda[index].unidades - 1);

            emit(
              ComandaLoaded(
                  comanda: state.comanda.copyWith(lineasComanda: nuevaLista)),
            );
          }

        } catch (_) {}
      }
    });
```

Comment: on<AddUnidades>((event, emit) async {
      final state = this.state;
      if (state is ComandaLoaded) {
        try {
      
          if (state.comanda.lineasComanda.contains(event.lineaComanda)) {
            List<LineaComanda> lineasComanda = List.from(state.comanda.lineasComanda);

            lineasComanda.firstWhere((item) => item == event.lineaComanda).unidades += 1;

            emit(
              ComandaLoaded(comanda: state.comanda.copyWith(lineasComanda: lineasComanda)),
            );
          }
          // }
        } catch (_) {}
      }

Comment: I ' ve tried with before code, but result doesn't change.

Comment: @JoseDavid also using `copyWith` of `LineaComanda` is needed, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

If the user interface isn't getting redrawn it's because the emmited state is the same as before.

With "Same as before" i mean that the `==` operator returns true.

I see that you are using equatable.
I personally prefer to override the `==` so that I have more control when deciding wether or not the two objects are the same.

Anyway, in your case, carefully check that you have correctly overridden the propery `props` of all the types you are using (IE, I can't see the implementation for the class `Articulo`).

You could also write some unit tests to make sure that all the types you create correctly implement `Equatable`.